# Access App Notification Settings for Lock screen on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, push-notification

**Q**: In iOS 8 we have a bunch of preferences available to the user in the Settings->Notifications->(App name) like "Allow notifications" & "Show notifications on Lock screen" etc. Is it possible to programmatically set/access these user settings ?

**Background**:
I have push notifications enabled in my app and successfully registered the device. But it seems that the call to `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications:` always returns `NO`, if the user has chosen to set the display alert type to None.

Why this behavior ? Even if the user has enabled "Allow notifications" & "Show notifications on Lock screen", it should mean that I as a user only want to see my notifications on the lock screen but not alert me when it's unlocked. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no way to access this information directly. I guess Apple wants to make sure that user's preferences aren't overridden by programmers. (Ex: Spam push notifications)